# HTTP Webrequest Not Sending Correct Request?

Tags: php

Does anyone know why I can request a URL via webbrowser, but not via http webrequest (GET) in PHP? On my VPS I have an HTTP listener listening on a certain port. When I request the URL, Port, and Path from my browser it works fine, but when I request the URL, Port, and Path from a PHP web request it does not work.

I tried using cURL and a few other methods such as http_get, but none of them seem to work. I think it may have to do with my headers, but I'm not entirely sure. Does anyone have any idea? If you do, please post them.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'URL';

     try {
        $response = fetchUrl($url);
        echo $response;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log('Fetch URL failed: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' for ' . $url);
    }

function fetchUrl($uri) {
    $handle = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $hlength  = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $body     = substr($response, $hlength);

    // If HTTP response is not 200, throw exception
    if ($httpCode != 200) {
        throw new Exception($httpCode);
    }

    return $body;
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You might wanna post the relevant code.

Comment: There, I have added the PHP code. The .net code is irrelevant as it works fine through a web browser, so the code should be fine.

Comment: Can you post the request/response trace with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), first with a web browser, then with your script?

Comment: so does it throw an exception ? have you tried echoing your response from the server before the exception ?

Comment: It keeps saying the connection timed out. Is it possible that since I am using a shared host that the port I am trying to connect through is not open? Then I would need to open the port correct?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.is it a port other than 80 ?